# J2me set font to the whole list

Tags: list, java-me, fonts, lcdui

There's a method `setFont(int listItem, Font font)` in `List` class which sets some font to the list item. So I have to run through the list items and set fonts in a cycle. Is there any method to set one font to the whole list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any method to set one font to the whole list?

There is no such method in MIDP 2.

Full list of available methods is provided in [lcdui List API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/List.html) - one can easily find out that `setFont(int, Font)` is the only one way to do that